# How to divide in assembly language using addition?

Tags: assembly, binary, cpu-architecture, opcode

In a computer engineering class in high-school, we were given an assignment where we have to divide 2 numbers in assembly language by using the process of addition.

The toy architecture we're programming for doesn't have a division instruction.  The machine has 2's complement addition and bitwise AND/OR/XOR operations, but not subtraction directly: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r03944025/intro2015/files/hw/appendix_c

(Editor's note, the textbook doesn't define a text assembly language, only machine code opcodes and operands for this load/store machine with sixteen 8-bit registers, and a conditional jump-if-zero instruction.)

Comment: Can you assume both your inputs are non-negative (or at least have the same sign)?  If not, you have to handle that possibility and work with absolute values.  Other than that, the algorithm is pretty trivial to find with google, e.g. [Division returning quotient and remainder using a loop and subtraction?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46749191).  A better algorithm (O(log n) instead of O(n)) is possible, e.g. [Implement division with bit-wise operator](//stackoverflow.com/q/5284898)

Comment: @PeterCordes - complicating matters in this case is the conditional branch is only for register x == register 0, no <, <=, >, or >=.

Comment: @rcgldr: That's a very good point.  But you can use `AND` + `BNZ` to test for a register being negative, so if you limit the range to signed values, you can use that.  So yeah, for divisions that leave a remainder, detecting the end is the non-trivial part of a loop like `do { quotient++; dividend += -divisor; } while( dividend >= 0 );`

Comment: @PeterCordes - Martin Rosenau covers this in his answer. Since these are 8 bit registers, this could be done slowly with 3 incrementing counters (or decrementing as needed for negative numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I don't want to do your school homework, I will only give you some hints:

> How to divide ... using addition?

It is not the fasted method, but you can do the following:

```
; Calculate C = A / B
Set C to 0
As long as A >= B:
    Increment C by 1
    Subtract B from A
```

If A and B may be negative, do the following:

```
Set D to 0
If A is negative:
    Set D to 1
    Negate A
If B is negative:
    Xor D with 1
    Negate B
Perform C = A / B (see above)
If D != 0:
    Negate C
```

> The toy architecture ... has 2's complement addition and bitwise AND/OR/XOR operations ...

... and a conditional jump instruction that jumps if two registers are equal as well as a rotate operation.

This is very important because with bitwise operations and addition only, bit 0 of the result of some operation would only depend on bit 0 of the operands. This means that bit 0 of the final output of some program would only depend on bit 0 of the inputs.

However, for the two divisions 0x30 / 0x10 = 3 and 0x20 / 0x10 = 2 bit 0 of all inputs is 0, but in one case bit 0 of the output is 1 and in the other case bit 0 of the output is 0.

> but not subtraction directly

Some hints about some operations your CPU does not have:

- Inverting all bits of a number can be done with a XOR operation.
- Please recall how to negate a number in two's complement.
- If you are able to negate a number and to add numbers, you should also be able to subtract numbers.
- Please recall how to find out if a two's complement's number is negative.
- If you operate with numbers in the range 0...127 only, checking for "A<B" can be done by checking for "(A-B) is negative".
  Note that this is the case when you allow negative inputs!
- If you are operating with the whole range 0...255, checking for "A<B" is more difficult:

  - If bit 7 is "1" in A but "0" in B, then A<B is false
  - If bit 7 is "0" in A but "1" in B, then A<B is true
  - If bit 7 has the same value in A and B (either both bits are "0" or both bits are "1"), the check for "(A-B) is negative" can be done